# How to convert a numpy array of strings which have arrays within the strings to an array of strings?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have data which is of type `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`, in each string there is an array with strings inside them.

```
['[ABC]' '["ABC"]' '["ABC" "Pasticultores del Desierto"]'
 '[UNIQUE Forestry and Land Use]' '[]' '[Urapi Sustainable Land Use]'
 '[CARANA]' '[AF]' '[AAF]' '[CATIE]' '["Moring" "CIRAD"]' '[Moringa]'
 '[12Tree Finance]' '["AF" "CIMA"]' '["Andes Amazon Fund"]'
 '[Kaeté_Investimentos]' '[Pomeroon]' '[FCCF]' '[12Tree Fund]' '[12Tree]'
 '[Symbiosis_Investimentos]' '[LLC]' '[AIDER]' '[WRI]' '[ISA]']
```

I am trying to convert them into an array with arrays of strings inside.

```
[["ABC"], ["ABC"], ["ABC" ,"Pasticultores del Desierto"],
 ["UNIQUE Forestry and Land Use"], [], ["Urapi Sustainable Land Use"],
 ["CARANA"], ["AF"], ["AAF"], ["CATIE"], ["Moring","CIRAD"] , ["Moringa"],
 ["12Tree Finance"], ["AF","CIMA"], ["Andes Amazon Fund"],
 ["Kaeté_Investimentos"] , ["Pomeroon"] , ["FCCF"] , ["12Tree Fund"] , ["12Tree"],
 ["Symbiosis_Investimentos"] , ["LLC"] , ["AIDER"] , ["WRI"] , ["ISA"]]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/how-to-convert-string-representation-of-list-to-a-list

Comment: The fact that it's an array doesn't help you.  You have to transform each string with string methods.